# is there any way to put a right path on JAVA_HOME?

Tags: flutter, dart

here the image show my current problem I do my best to modify the path. the path of JAVA_HOME is right but I've been confuse because that is always show up even though that I already modified it .if I try to put the directory path of my SDK it's the same error.

image link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeipD.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: JAVA\_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your flutter PATH. in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359564/error-java-home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like this in your Environment Variables.
[image: Java_path]

Answer (score 0):

Following steps solved problem for me

Locate where your `Android Studio` is installed.

> For me C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

1. Check if the `jre` folder exists, Create a new folder called `jre`
2. Copy the contents of the `jbr` folder and paste them into the *jre* folder.
3. Check by running `flutter doctor`, and Restart IDE.

Thanks: [roufy235](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502#issuecomment-1383215722) {[cause](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_studio.dart#L449-L451)}