# I having problem with my Android Studio (version 2022.1)

Tags: flutter, android-studio

SS from my Windows PowerShell

[image]

Can someone help me with solve this problem?

I already try to search for solutions for hours and still having the same problem

Comment: did you install java? try `java` command on terminal

Comment: This should solve your issue>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter

Comment: Yes, I already install java and I already tried to copy all of the files in "jbr\bin" to "jre\bin". When I run flutter doctor, it says "Unable to determine bundled Java version."

Comment: do you get output from `java` command? make sure to add envPath and JavaHome on environment

Comment: Yes, I get an output from java command. Im sorry, how to add envPath and JavaHome on environment?

Comment: if you get output, you mostly dont need to set, try to follow this >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526703/10157127

Comment: I already done that but still got the same problem. Do I need to uninstall everything and re-install again?

Comment: yea you can do it, try to follow the official doc and you may also find good yt video

Comment: Glad to help, you can follow https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to find bundled Java version on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter)