# java variable path in system envirnoment

Tags: java, flutter, oop

When I am using command prompt then write a doctor flutter --android-licenses then an error show on
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

I tied to add a java variable in system environment but when I open it again command prompt writes again the error remains same

Comment: Ok. What did you set it to? What happens when you `echo %JAVA_HOME%`? Are you on Windows? Where did you install Java? Please don't ask us to guess.

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after setting `JAVA_HOME`? If you adjust your environment, properties might not be reloaded. To be completely sure it might be wise to restart or simply logout / login in your OS :)

Comment: Already answered. this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/68496027/20230760

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: JAVA\_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your flutter PATH. In Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359564/error-java-home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your-flutter)