# flutter app building time error of Java.exe not found

Tags: java, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe

what's solution for this.
i also set JAVA_HOME environment variable but also give error.

solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer that i followed,It really worked for me so try it as well,here is the link of the answer [answer link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526703/20281089)

Answer (score 0):

1. open the directory of android  Studio

   C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe

delete the bin folder and  go to the

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
```

folder and copy the all directory and paste it in

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\
```

in this location  that all

2. delete tha jre folder and restart the your android studio and its rebuild