# Gradle task assembleDebug failed. JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: flutter

I got the following error while runing my flutter app without debugging in android emulator in vs code:-
'''
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
'''

I have been experiencing this issue since some time. My flutter application does not run on the android emulator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359564/error-java-home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your-flutter Have you tried the solutions here?

Comment: I tried the solution in the link you provided. thanks for the help. That error is now gone. However, now I am geting another set of errors when running my program.