# JVM DLL not found. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, java, visual-studio-code, dll, jvm

Trying to explore using Tabula in python on a PDF in Visual Studio code on MacOS.

```
import pandas as pd
import tabula
dfs = tabula.read_pdf("/Users/TEST.pdf", pages = 1)
len(dfs)
```

When I run the code however I get the following error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] JVM DLL not found: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib

[image]

I have installed Java via home-brew, and via a pkg all apparently successful and can run a simple java program in visual studio code just fine. So it is installed, but I don't really know how to solve the above error despite a few attempts.

[image]

I am really new to python and installing packages so if you think you can answer, please walk me through like I'm 5 years old.

UPDATE:

```
import os

# Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the Java installation directory
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk"

import pandas as pd
import tabula
dfs = tabula.read_pdf("/Users/NickCoding/Desktop/TEST.pdf", pages = 1)
len(dfs)
```

This allows the code to work, however I feel that this is a botched solution.

How do I get it to work in the virtual environment?

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526703/19133920) to set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME ` for your system

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: Latest update I offered as a edit to my question though didnt feel it was good enough as an answer. Will look into the linked answer you hav provided.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found a solution.

1. Install Java Run Time
2. Install JDK https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk22-mac
3. export JAVA HOME To export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 14`