# Gradle task assembleDebug failing due to previous javaHome being searched for while running Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, gradlew

I'm a new user to Flutter and originally downloaded it with jdk-20 as the version of Java on my system. However, after realizing that jdk-20 was incompatible with certain Flutter processes, I uninstalled it and installed jdk-17 instead. Now when I try emulating an Android app, gradle keeps searching for the folder with my previous version of Java (jdk-20), despite me having updated the environment variables.

I get no issues when running flutter doctor, or when running Flutter for simulating anything other than Android. I tried solving this using the solutions listed here [ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your flutter PATH. In Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359564/error-java-home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your-flutter), but nothing worked, as it seems to be something wrong with only gradle and not Android Studio.

I tried running ./gradlew clean build but those commands also failed due to the same "Supplied javaHome is invalid" error.

The error logs I get with flutter run -v

```
[   +2 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[  +10 ms] executing: [D:\Programs\Flutter_projects\first_app\first_app\android/]
D:\Programs\Flutter_projects\first_app\first_app\android\gradlew.bat --full-stacktrace --info -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-x86 
-Ptarget=D:\Programs\Flutter_projects\first_app\first_app\lib\main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application
-Pdart-defines=RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ==,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQ0FOVkFTS0lUX1VSTD1odHRwczovL3d3dy5nc3RhdGljLmNvbS9mbHV0dGVyLWNhbnZ
hc2tpdC9iZDk4NmM1ZWQyMGE2MmRjMzRiNzcxOGM1MGFiYzc4MmJlYWU0YzMzLw== -Pdart-obfuscation=false -Ptrack-widget-creation=true
-Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[ +862 ms] Initialized native services in: C:\Users\sukes\.gradle\native
[   +1 ms] Initialized jansi services in: C:\Users\sukes\.gradle\native
[ +571 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +2 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: D:\Program
Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\java.exe
[   +1 ms] * Try:
[   +1 ms] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[   +1 ms] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Exception is:
[   +1 ms] org.gradle.internal.jvm.JavaHomeException: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried  
location: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\java.exe
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.findExecutable(Jvm.java:183)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.getJavaExecutable(Jvm.java:208)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.forHome(Jvm.java:119)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DaemonCompatibilitySpec.javaHomeMatches(DaemonCompatibilitySpec.java:64)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DaemonCompatibilitySpec.whyUnsatisfied(DaemonCompatibilitySpec.java:40)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DaemonCompatibilitySpec.isSatisfiedBy(DaemonCompatibilitySpec.java:35)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.context.DaemonCompatibilitySpec.isSatisfiedBy(DaemonCompatibilitySpec.java:25)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.getCompatibleDaemons(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:192)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connectToIdleDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:157)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:125)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:145)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:99)
[   +3 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:57)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:210)
[   +1 ms]      at
org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:275)
[   +2 ms]      at
org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:247)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:82)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:30)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:92)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:38)
[   +3 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:44)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:26)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:41)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:26)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:240)   
[   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[   +2 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[   +2 ms]      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:34)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[   +2 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[   +2 ms]      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[   +2 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[  +64 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 1,575ms)
[+12615 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is what shows up when I run flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2428], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.13.5 on channel stable at D:\flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 12fccda598 (8 weeks ago), 2023-09-19 13:56:11 -0700
    • Engine revision bd986c5ed2
    • Dart version 3.1.2
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at D:\AppData
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.6)
    • Visual Studio at D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.7.34221.43
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.3
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.84.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\sukes\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.76.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2428]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.118
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 119.0.2151.58

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after trying a lot of things I got the bright idea to look in my Java folder, where I discovered that despite uninstalling jdk-20 the folder still existed inside of the Java folder. It didn't contain anything inside of it, but I deleted it just to see what would happen.

And that turned out to be what had been causing the issue. After I deleted it, everything started to work fine using jdk-17. I'm still not sure *why* an empty folder was the cause of the problem, so if anyone could explain that I'd greatly appreciate it. Anyway, I'll leave this answer here in case anyone else ends up facing the same issue.