# Could not determine the dependencies :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-33. i am tring to run a simple flutter project and having this error.

I have updated my sdks and now facing this error, even  simple flutter demo project is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm writing here. First of all can you give the `flutter doctor -v` results maybe there is something Flutter Doctor actually explains to you. Since I don't have enough information I'm just going to give you standart solutions that might work for you:

- Ensure that Android SDK is installed. You can do this with Android Studio program or IntellijIdea (If you're not going to use Intellij, you can install Android Studio)
- Sometimes environment variables (most common is JAVA_HOME) did not set correctly. So check that, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359564/error-java-home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your-flutter) stackoverflow answer.
- Since your problem is with Android OS, you have to agree the terms (if not flutter doctor will show you the right command but it was `flutter doctor --android-licenses`)
- If you've already done those, maybe you didn't install API Level 13 (Android 33) exclusively check that.
- If none of these works I'm sorry I don't know enough information to help you, but if you give more info I'd be happy to help

Happy coding