I'm facing an issue with building my Flutter app. Despite ensuring the correct JAVA_HOME environment variable is set, I keep getting the error
I'm facing an issue with building my Flutter app. Despite ensuring the correct JAVA_HOME environment variable is set, I keep getting the error:

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin

Steps taken:

Checked and corrected JAVA_HOME: I've verified that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set correctly to the root directory of my JDK installation (e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17).
Reinstalled JDK: I've uninstalled and reinstalled the JDK multiple times.
Cleaned Flutter project: I've run flutter clean to remove temporary files.
Restarted system: I've restarted my system to ensure changes take effect.


The JAVA_HOME should point to the root of the jdk, eg C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 and not the "bin" folder.

I've already set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the correct root directory of my JDK installation (e.g., C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17) without \bin at the end. I've also ensured that the %JAVA_HOME%\bin path is added to my system's PATH variable.
I'm still encountering the following error:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin

The error is clear, your JAVA_HOME does include \bin while it shouldn't. If you changed the value of JAVA_HOME, then you need to restart the application or terminal/command prompt you're using, as it will use the value the environment variable had when it started (and programs run from the command prompt, or another application, inherit it from the command prompt, or that application).

And if the error persists after restarting, then double check if you haven't set JAVA_HOME both in your user and system properties, and maybe if there is a start up script or application-specific configuration (e.g. in your IDE) that overrides JAVA_HOME.

The JAVA_HOME variable should point to the root directory of the JDK, not the bin directory. Try set it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 (without \bin at the end).

Optional: If you want java/javac on the PATH (e.g., you want to run them directly outside Flutter) you can also have an entry in your PATH (System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables) pointing to %JAVA_HOME%\bin.

I've already set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the correct root directory of my JDK installation (e.g., C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17) without \bin at end. I've also ensured that the %JAVA_HOME%\bin path is added to my system's PATH variable.
Despite these steps, I'm still encountering the following error when building my Flutter app:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin

Restart your shell/vscode terminal etc. then try.  Maybe also check out the options here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359564/error-java-home-is-not-set-and-no-java-command-could-be-found-in-your-flutter

Had the same issue resolved it this way , so Flutter has a flutter configuration to set a certain function one of the most affected configs is jdk-dir if the flutter is set the jdk-dir it will override the JAVA_HOME configuration on your environment variables.
You can open up your terminal and type this command
flutter config --jdk-dir="path_to_jdk"
for example flutter config --jdk-dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17" and you can test it by running you can read more on this from this article https://medium.com/@faidfadjri/flutter-error-java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory-74c829b6e067
